# Resource intepreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post to an `Action` from a jQuery modal and have that action return JSON. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Resource intepreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json
```

And then my browser redirects to the page with the url path of my action and only displays the JSON as a string.

Note that I'm able to post to my controller just fine, it's when the return Json(...) gets called that for some reason it redirects to the URL of my post action than to return to my ajax call.

Here is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(MyModel model)
{
     return Json(...);
}
```

My JS:

```
 $('form')
            .submit(function() {
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.action,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "post",
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                            $('#formContent').html(result);
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$(this).serialize()` as your data - your data will be a string (as this is the result of the `serialize` function.

If you want your data to be in json notation you **might** wanna use `$(this).serializeArray()`. Note that the `serializeArray` function will give you the data as something like that:

```
[
    {
        name: "a",
        value: "1"
    },
    {
        name: "b",
        value: "2"
    },
    {
        name: "c",
        value: "3"
    },
    {
        name: "d",
        value: "4"
    },
    {
        name: "e",
        value: "5"
    }
]
```

So in case you need to change the data to `{ 'a' : '1', 'b' : '2', 'c' : '3'}` you might need to work a bit on the data before sending it to the server.